# Is it okay if Operational data store holds data for rolling time period?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

We are planning to build an Operational data store for the front-end users data extraction requirements. 
As far as I know the Kimball's approach to build ODS\DW, it should hold the data for complete time period and not like the rolling time period.

The reason being, there could be a need to extract older data from ODS\DW.

So I need your thoughts on this. How should I approach ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a snapshot table that could hold the values for the rolling period for each day, and filter on the client side of things which snapshot to display.

Once the period is over then the final values can be stored on the permanent data mart.

Comment: "permanent data mart" you mean ODS or DW ? We already have a set up of EDW. But this is per the operational need we are creating ODS.

Comment: Either. The same principle applies. Keep to date incomplete periods on a snapshot table and insert into historical table once period finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Kimball's approach for a data warehouse would be to load transactional data to any data warehouse if you can, because it is more flexible in terms of being rolled up. Certainly at the ODS stage you wouldn't want to 'pre-aggregate' your data, if there could be a need to get hold of older data.

If you store both the transactional data and then pre-aggregated versions of the data (in aggregate fact tables, with indexes/views or with a cube, or just filtering on the report side as the other answer suggests), you can get the best of both worlds.

(Note: Kimball's approach in fact does not require an ODS: they're fine if you want to build one, but their focus is on the dimensionally modelled data warehouse.)